# WithPagination with bootstrap 4 as paginationTheme not working as intended in livewire

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-livewire

I have made a simple project in Laravel. I am using Livewire v^2.2.

When I add the code as described in the documentation, the previous and next buttons are dead.

The code in php Component is:

```
// If I comment this out, the view is horrible but is working.
   // use WithPagination;
    
        // protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
    
        public function render()
        {
            return view('livewire.users', [
                'users' => User::paginate(1),
            ]);
        }
```

In the template:

```
<div>
    <h1>Users</h1>
    <div class="list-group">
    @foreach($users as $user)

            <a href="" class="list-group-item list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                    <h5 class="mb-1">{{ $user->name }}</h5>
                    <small>{{ $user->created_at }}</small>
                </div>
                <p class="mb-1">{{ $user->email }}</p>
            </a>
    @endforeach
    </div>
    <br>
    {{ $users->links() }}
</div>
```

Comment: do you have more than 1 user in the database?

Comment: I'm not sure `bootstrap` exists based on this https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/8.x/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views can you try `boostrap-4` ?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class NameComponent extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
```

add this in side Livewire view

```
<div>
.....

    @push('scripts')
        <script>
            Livewire.restart();
        </script>
    @endpush
</div>
```

in layouts/app.blade.php after @livewireScripts  add @stack('scripts')

```
<body>
    ...
    @livewireScripts
    
    @stack('scripts')
</body>
```

Comment: I have tried this, I do get the pagination buttons now but there is no events triggered.

Comment: protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';  did the trick .... great answer thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why.

Livewire components MUST have a single root element.

I forgot to add the top line in the question i see.